# Jupyter notebook error "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook

When I want to simply `import keras` in jupyter notebook, I got an error `"The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."`
My code is only:

```
import keras
```

Comment: Try restarting the jupyter notebook server

Comment: Thanks @AdityaMishra But not works! I even restart my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question. To solve the problem, I had to uninstall and reinstall anaconda and then use `pip install tensorflow`. :(